# Visual Studio is not generating PollingDuplex Proxy Client

Tags: wcf, silverlight, pollingduplexhttpbinding

Visual Studio is not creating a constructor for my PollingDuplex proxy. There should be 8 constructors for WCF Client with a constructor including HttpPollingDuplexBinding object and an Endpoint address. But there are only 5 overloads and the client does not have Callback methods. 
How can I fix this problem?

```
        var address = new EndpointAddress("http://"
            + App.Current.Host.Source.DnsSafeHost
            + ":"
            + App.Current.Host.Source.Port.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            + "/PService.svc");
        return new ServiceClient(binding, address);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue as mentioned here

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2010/04/04/some-known-wcf-issues-in-silverlight-4.aspx

But still can not produce all the constructors. Though I believe this could be an answer for someone who faces this problem.

Edit:

Very strange.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyCallback
{

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginNotify(Message message, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    void EndNotify(IAsyncResult result);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnX();
}
```

works fine. But this

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPokerClient
{

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnX();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginNotify(Message message, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    void EndNotify(IAsyncResult result);

}
```

is not working fine here. I have no idea but I'm changing nothing but this and getting a proxy with callback functions.